# Waiting until boolean value is changed without blocking main JavaFX thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency, blocking

I have been reading for hours about different multi-threading techniques for JavaFX and cannot seem to find what I'm looking for. The application being worked on is the "Messenger" which part of a bigger application to provide a trading marketplace for a game.

A breakdown of the process I am having trouble with:

- A window with a 'Contact Seller' button is displayed
- The user clicks 'Contact Seller', and the Messenger window should be displayed
- Using the seller's name from the main window, the Messenger should check if a chat already exists with that name
- If the chat already exists, get the index of that chat in the Messenger's ListView, and select the chat so the Messenger's text area is populated with the corresponding messages
- If the chat doesn't exist, create one

**The issue:**

- Chats are stored server-side
- Messages between clients are stored in a message 'cache' on the server when being processed from one user to the other (they are sorted to their respective chats, inserted into the chats, and pushed to the database upon client disconnection)
- Messages received on the client are stored locally in the respective chat
- When the Messenger is opened, it requests a list of chats for the signed-in user
- The server sends an ArrayList of chats, and upon receiving the client builds the Messenger's ListView with these objects

Now when I need to open the Messenger in order to 'Contact Seller', I need to make sure the sync with the server is complete. Without doing so, I won't be able to properly check if a chat already exists with that name since I won't have the most up-to-date list.

The 'RequestWorker' thread that handles incoming server messages is NOT on the JavaFX thread.

The RequestWorker 'gets' the Messenger instance if it is currently open, and populates the ListView with the newly received chat list. (This needs to happen on the JavaFX thread, since I am working in the Messenger GUI)

What I am trying to do is set a static AtomicBoolean syncInProgress to true when the Messenger initiates a sync upon being displayed. When the RequestWorker receives the latest list back from the server and finishes populating the Messengers ListView, it sets syncInProgress to false.

The sync takes longer than opening the Messenger and making it check if a chat exists. Doing it this way it has no items populated yet in the ListView and the method is ineffective.

Calling a while loop to wait until the boolean is changed, blocks the JavaFX thread which means the RequestWorker cannot do what it needs to in the JavaFX thread.

How can I continuously check for this variable to be set false, then continue to 'Contact Seller' once the ListView has been properly populated?

**Contact Seller method:** The while loop in here causes a block on the JavaFX thread, thus not enabling RequestWorker to properly populate the ListView.

```
public static void contactSeller(Messenger messenger, String destination, String itemName)
{
    while (TarkovTrader.syncInProgress.get())
    {
        ; // Wait until sync is complete to check the latest chat list for an existing chat
    }

    if (messenger.chatExists(destination))
    {
        // Chat exists, select the chat for the user
        for (Chat openChat : messenger.chatListView.getItems())
        {
            if (openChat.getName(TarkovTrader.username).equals(destination))
            {
                messenger.chatListView.getSelectionModel().select(openChat);
                messenger.unpackChatMessages(openChat.getMessages());
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        messenger.buildNewChat(destination);
    }

    messenger.chatInput.setText("Hey " + destination + ". Interested in your '" + itemName + "'.");
    messenger.chatInput.setOnMouseClicked(e -> messenger.chatInput.clear());        
}
```

**RequestWorker process chat block:**

```
switch(receivedFromServer)
            case "chatlist":
            // Client requested a chat list, results were returned from the server, and now we need to populate the messenger list
            ChatListForm chatlistform = (ChatListForm)processedRequest;

            if (Messenger.isOpen)
            {   
                FutureTask<Void> updateChatList = new FutureTask(() -> {
                    Messenger tempMessenger = trader.getMessenger();
                    int currentIndex = tempMessenger.chatListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                    tempMessenger.populate(chatlistform.getChatList());
                    tempMessenger.chatListView.getSelectionModel().select(currentIndex);
                }, null);

                Platform.runLater(updateChatList);  // RequestWorker needs access to the JavaFX application thread

                try { 
                    updateChatList.get(); // Wait until the ListView has been populated before setting 'syncInProgress' to false again
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                    Alert.display(null, "Sync interrupted.");
                }
                catch (ExecutionException e) { 
                    Alert.display(null, "Sync failed.");
                }

                TarkovTrader.syncInProgress.compareAndSet(true, false);  // The value of syncInProgress should be true, change to false. Sync complete
            }

            else
            {
                Platform.runLater(() -> Alert.display(null, "New chat received."));
                TarkovTrader.syncInProgress.compareAndSet(true, false);
            }                

            break;
```

**Contact Seller button logic:** If a messenger is not open, create it and pass to static `contactSeller` method to use.

```
    contactButton.setOnAction(e -> {

        Messenger messenger;

        if (Messenger.isOpen)
        {
            // Get messenger
            messenger = trader.getMessenger();
        }
        else
        {
            messenger = new Messenger(worker);
            messenger.display();
            trader.setMessenger(messenger);      
        }

        Messenger.contactSeller(messenger, item.getUsername(), item.getName());

        itemdisplay.close();

    });
```

EDIT: 
Partially using Slaw's idea (AtomicBoolean is still being used since I'm not sure how to do this without it), this is what I came up with...

```
public static void contactSeller(Messenger messenger, String destination, String itemName)
{
    Task<Void> waitForSync = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call()
        {
            while (TarkovTrader.syncInProgress.get())
            {
                ; // Wait until sync is complete
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    waitForSync.setOnSucceeded(e -> {

        while (TarkovTrader.syncInProgress.get())
        {
            ; // Wait until sync is complete to check the latest chat list for an existing chat
        }

        if (messenger.chatExists(destination))
        {
            // Chat exists, select the chat for the user
            for (Chat openChat : messenger.chatListView.getItems())
            {
                if (openChat.getName(TarkovTrader.username).equals(destination))
                {
                    messenger.chatListView.getSelectionModel().select(openChat);
                    messenger.unpackChatMessages(openChat.getMessages());
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            messenger.buildNewChat(destination);
        }

        messenger.chatInput.setText("Hey " + destination + ". Interested in your '" + itemName + "'.");
        messenger.chatInput.setOnMouseClicked(me -> messenger.chatInput.clear());        

    });

    Thread t = new Thread(waitForSync);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

Which does work, but this doesn't seem like a great solution. Is it fine to do something like this or is there a preferred method over this? I feel like the while loop and using a triggered boolean is sloppy..but is this common practice?

Comment: You mention reading up on different multi-threading options in JavaFX so maybe you've already considered this, but... why don't you use a [`javafx.concurrent.Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)? Rather than using an `AtomicBoolean` flag and busy waiting you'd use the [`onSucceeded` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#onSucceededProperty) to execute code on the FX thread once the `Task` completes successfully.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the reply! I've been thinking about how to implement this but I'm not exactly sure how to make it work since 'contactSeller' is not necessarily always called after performing a sync. Can you give me an idea on how to implement?

Comment: @Slaw i added a code snippet in at the bottom. I know this is not what you were suggesting but I'm not sure exactly how to implement this without the boolean playing some kind of factor. The boolean is the only way I know the client has received the list back from the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX UI blocked while another Thread is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844344/javafx-ui-blocked-while-another-thread-is-running)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to handle the opened chat in the same method that schedules the chat retrieval. Instead create a queue of handlers that is executed as soon as the chat is ready.

Simplified Example

```
public class ChatManager {

    private final Map<String, Chat> openChats = new HashMap<>();

    // only call from application thread
    public void openChat(String user, Consumer<Chat> chatReadyHandler) {
        Chat chat = openChats.computeIfAbsent(user, this::createNewChat);
        chat.addReadyHandler(chatReadyHandler);
    }

    private Chat createNewChat(String user) {
        return new Chat(user);
    }

    public class Chat {

        // list keeping track of handlers any used for synchronisation
        private final ArrayList<Consumer<Chat>> readyHandlers = new ArrayList<>(1);
        private boolean ready = false;
        private final String user;

        public String getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        private void addReadyHandler(Consumer<Chat> chatReadyHandler) {
            synchronized (readyHandlers) {
                // if already ready, immediately execute, otherwise enqueue
                if (ready) {
                    chatReadyHandler.accept(this);
                } else {
                    readyHandlers.add(chatReadyHandler);
                }
            }
        }

        private void chatReady() {
            synchronized (readyHandlers) {
                ready = true;
            }
            // execute all handlers on the application thread
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                synchronized (readyHandlers) {
                    for (Consumer<Chat> readyHandler : readyHandlers) {
                        readyHandler.accept(this);
                    }
                    readyHandlers.clear();
                    readyHandlers.trimToSize();
                }
            });
        }

        private Chat(String user) {
            this.user = user;
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // simulate time required to acquire chat
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                chatReady();
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

The following code creates a `Chat` with a user when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed after typing the user name in the `TextField` and prints a message to the `TextArea` when the chat is ready.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ChatManager worker = new ChatManager();

    TextField userName = new TextField();
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    userName.setOnAction(evt -> {
        String user = userName.getText();
        userName.clear();
        textArea.appendText("opening chat for " + user + "\n");
        worker.openChat(user, chat -> textArea.appendText("chat for " + chat.getUser() + " ready\n"));
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, userName, textArea));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```